# Hibernate equivalent for TIMESTAMP query

Tags: hibernate

Just out of curiosity, what is the best way to accomplish this using hibernate

```
   select * 
   from USERS 
   where TO_CHAR(CREATE_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') = '1972-   07-31 13:52:50.381000'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Date date = dateFormat.parse("1972-07-31 13:52:50.381");
String hql = "select u from User u where u.createTimestamp = :timestamp";
return session.createQuery(hql).setTimestamp("timestamp", date).list();
```

Comment: And the solution would be exactly the same. You create a date in Java, and add `Restrictions.eq("user.createTimestamp", timestamp)` to the criteria.

Comment: the value in db is '1972-07-31 13:52:50.381000' so just using '1972-07-31 13:52:50.381' will not work with a equals clause??

Comment: It's a timestamp. It's not a string. What you're seeing is a human-readable representation of a timestamp. So it's just like the real number 1.5 is equal to the real number 1.5000.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the criteria api:
Just after posting, I got it to work as follows:

```
Criteria criteria = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("TO_CHAR(CREATE_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')='1972-07-31 13:52:50.381000'"));
```